# #22 Project Euler: Why is my answer wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve [Problem 22](https://projecteuler.net/problem=22) on Project Euler:

> Using [`names.txt`](https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p022_names.txt) (right click and 'Save Link/Target As...'), a 46K text
>   file containing over five-thousand first names, begin by sorting it
>   into alphabetical order. Then working out the alphabetical value for
>   each name, multiply this value by its alphabetical position in the
>   list to obtain a name score.
>
> For example, when the list is sorted into alphabetical order, COLIN,
>   which is worth 3 + 15 + 12 + 9 + 14 = 53, is the 938th name in the
>   list. So, COLIN would obtain a score of 938 × 53 = 49714.
>
> What is the total of all the name scores in the file?

The contents of `names.txt` are

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH","JENNIFER","MARIA",....[46k omitted]
```

I don't understand why I get an answer that is incorrect when I use this code:

```
import os
chart=open('names.txt')
doc=chart.read()
doc=doc.split(',')
doc.sort()
z=0

def nameNum(name):
    r=0
    for letter in name:
        r=r+ord(letter) - 64
    return r

for string in doc:
    z+=(doc.index(string)+1)*nameNum(string)
print z
```

I was trying to make z produce the answer but it isn't correct and I can't figure out why.

This is python 3 by the way.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also, this cannot be Python 3, since you use `print z` which only works in Python 2

Comment: In the answer I cannot post, I advised you to write a testable function such as `allsum` and then apply it to simple inputs, starting with `' "" '` and `' "A", '`, for which you can calculate the answer.  Only try `allsum(open('names.txt').read())` after something like `allsum(''' "CD","A","AB" ''')` works.

Answer (score 3):

You're scoring the quotes `"` along with the names. The easiest is to just remove them before splitting at comma;

```
...
doc=chart.read()
doc=doc.replace('"', '')
doc=doc.split(',') 
...
```

Before the fix, you're getting a negative score for COLIN

```
Name: "COLIN", pos: 938, score: -6566
```

...but after the fix it's correct according to the example;

```
Name: COLIN, pos: 938, score: 49714
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your actual algorithm, but the problem is that while you split the file by `,`, there are still `"` characters around each name; so you're incorrectly adding `2 * (64 - ord('"'))` to the score of each name, which is why you get an incorrect result.

The file is in a format that could be easily parsed by `ast.literal_eval()` into a tuple of strings:

```
import ast
with open('names.txt') as f:
     contents = f.read()
     names = sorted(ast.literal_eval(contents))
```

Now `names` is a sorted list of names, without any extra characters. Using this list instead of your `doc`, I got the correct result from your algorithm.

---

Also while this does not affect the algorithm itself, using `.index` to find the index of items is very inefficient:

```
for string in doc:
    z+=(doc.index(string)+1)*nameNum(string)
```

you should [use `enumerate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops) instead:

```
for number, name in enumerate(names, start=1):
    z += number * nameNum(name)
```

Now `names` is a sorted list of names, without any extra characters. With these changes I got the correct result.